# Lazy loading and scrollable table with Wicket 7

Tags: wicket

While migrating a Wicket 1.4 based web application which uses the `DojoLazyLoadingListContainer` from `org.wicketstuff.dojo` to newer Wicket 7 we identified major problems.
The migration of the lazy loading table itselfs seems not to be a feasible solution and we are looking for another table providing our functional requirements:

- Infinite scrollable with lazy loading via the standard Wicket data provider concept.
- No pageable table style like Wicket standard
- Full AJAX support while replacing the loaded table for example in a
  tabbed view panel or in multiple wizard steps.
- Open source or commercial license for one web server and development
  systems
- We are looking for a Wicket data table implementation which is
  available for current Wicket version (e.g., 7.2.0) and has a
  future-proof on-going development.

Thanks for any help or hint in advance!

Kind regards,
Marc

Answer (score 2):

Check https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/datatables-parent.
It provides an integration with DataTables.net.
It has a demo of infinite scroll table at https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/datatables-parent/datatables-examples/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/datatables/demo/infiniteScroll.
Please use WicketStuff issues for bug reports!

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the DataTable with infinite scroll from the Wicket Jquery/Kendo UI project. It works with both wicket 6 and 7.

[www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/kendo/datatable/InfiniteDataTablePage](http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/kendo/datatable/InfiniteDataTablePage)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the link, I think it's a promising approach.
But I opend the InfiniteScrollDemoPage via a link and got this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Called operation not supported for TokenBuffer
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer._reportUnsupportedOperation(TokenBuffer.java:1031)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer.writeRawValue(TokenBuffer.java:694)
     at de.agilecoders.wicket.jquery.util.serializer.ConfigSerializer.serialize(ConfigSerializer.java:18)
     at de.agilecoders.wicket.jquery.util.serializer.ConfigSerializer.serialize(ConfigSerializer.java:15)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:467)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:388)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:27)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1837)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.valueToTree(ObjectMapper.java:1965)
     at de.agilecoders.wicket.jquery.util.Json.toJson(Json.java:73)
     at de.agilecoders.wicket.jquery.util.Json.stringify(Json.java:140)
     at de.agilecoders.wicket.jquery.AbstractConfig.toJsonString(AbstractConfig.java:35)
     at de.agilecoders.wicket.jquery.function.ConfigurableFunction.<init>(ConfigurableFunction.java:38)
     at de.agilecoders.wicket.jquery.JQuery.chain(JQuery.java:350)
     at org.wicketstuff.datatables.DataTables.renderHead(DataTables.java:72)
     at org.wicketstuff.datatables.demo.infiniteScroll.InfiniteScrollDemoPage$2.renderHead(InfiniteScrollDemoPage.java:75)
```

Comment: It seems that you use old version of Jackson library. Update it to 2.7+. Or check what the -example module uses.

Comment: Please don't use answers like forum posts. Either add a comment to the original answer or open a new question.